# checkbox and copy row to other Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

When a checkbox is ticked in column Q of sheet A i want to automatically copy the data of specific columns of sheet A to sheet B.

No clue for the best way to start; apps script, combined formulas? Saw some examples but not a clear one to start with.

Comment: Your title says copy row but the first line of your explanation says copy column.  So which is it?  I gave you and example for copying column.  If you wish row, that's for you to figure out.  If you you're a  programmer you will most likely have no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an onEdit trigger:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast('Gate1');
    let col = sh.getRange(2,e.range.columnStart,sh.getLastRow()- 1).getValues().flat().map(c => [c]);
    let osh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    osh.getRange(2,e.range.columnStart,col.length,col[0].length).setValues(col)
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]

Sheet1:

[image]